# Как удалить локальную ссылку на несуществующую уже удаленую ветку?

Tags: git

В локальном репозитории вижу следующую картину:

```
|
|
* <branch_name> origin/<branch_name>
|
```

На сервере (битбакет) этой ветки уже нет и давно.

```
git push origin :<branch_name>
```

логично выдает

```
remote ref doesn't exist
```

Как мне удалить локальную ссылку на несуществующую уже удаленную ветку?

Comment: git fetch --prune?

Comment: Оформите как ответ. Частично помогло, удалило часть уже не существующих на сервере веток. Часть осталось. Оставшиеся ветки удаляются --delete . Хотя их тоже на удаленке уже нет. Очень странное поведение битбакета.

Comment: это не удалит локал бранчи, их надо поудалять ручками

Comment: Про локал бранчи понятно, речь именно о ссылках, origin/branch_name на удаленые ветки которых реально там уже нет. Часть удаляет делетом, а вот оставщуюся часть - --prune. Почему то только некоторые ветки он считает удалено не существующими, хотя на сервере я не вижу не одну из них

Comment: Это не странное поведение битбакета, это обычное поведение гита. fetch --prune - он удаляет только референсы на удаленный репо и это логично. Если бы было не так: Вот была у вас ветка "mySuperFeature", и на удаленном репо она была. Потом админ вася решил почистить репо от фигни и вашу ветку совершенно случайно снес. Вы сделали fetch --prune и ваша фича незаметно потерялась. Все в отчаянии.

Comment: Вы не поняли опять :) я не говорю об удалении локальных веток. Я именно о ссылках, которые Вася на серваке давно удалил. Ссылки на эти ветки сервера висят. Например * local_branch origin/branch      local_branch понятно что будет на месте после prune, origin/branch не все уходят, ( приходится git push origin :branch)в этом странность

Comment: аа, все, да, понял что Вы имеете в виду. Да, тогда это действительно на битбакете и в чем тут косяк не знаю) К удаленной репо есть доступ чтобы отладиться?) Я предполагаю что это какая-нибудь фича битбакета с доступами видимостью веток криво настроена

Comment: А может просто баг, я нашел пару похожих issues в их трекере

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно выполнить команду [git fetch с флагом prune.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

```
git fetch --prune
```

Если удаленных репозиториев несколько, можно указать конкретный:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

То же самое:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Это удалит референсы на ветки удаленного репозитория, которых больше не существует.

При этом у вас могут еще остаться локальные ветки с которыми вы работали и которые раньше ссылались на несуществующие ветки удаленного репо.

Эти ветки надо поудалять ручками с помощью:

```
git branch -d
```

Comment: Можно удалить все замерженные локальные: `git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d`. Это не совсем то же, но почти.