# Почему ветки дублируются по разному?

Tags: git

Вот у меня есть удаленный репозиторий на `gitlab` и в разделе `branches` показывает мне все мои ветки. На данный момент она одна `master`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда я в терминале пишу команду `git branch -a` то получаю вот такой вывод

```
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Два вопроса

1. От куда подтягивается ветка `remotes/origin/develop`?
2. Как удалить `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`?

Когда я пробую использовать команду `$ git push origin --delete ветка`, то я не успеваю дописать и получаю странное предупреждение

```
git push origin --delete rwarning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/a
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/a
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/a
```

Как удалить ветку `develop`?

И насчет вот этой строчки `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` я так понимаю, что это указатель. Я помню когда то его удалял, чтоб не висел постоянно, только не помню как...

Вроде нужно какой то файл удалить где он хранит `HEAD` ... Подскажите кто помнит?

Comment: Откуда взялся `develop` я не знаю, но HEAD удалять не нужно, чем он Вам мешает?

Comment: хм. сколько ж раз нужно объяснить [про remotes/origin/head](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543282/178576)?

Comment: по поводу удаления локальных упоминаний про несуществующие в отдалённом хранилище указатели: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3184555/4827341

Comment: *Вроде нужно какой то файл удалить где он хранит `HEAD`...* -- так недолго и репозиторий поломать. Лучше не трогайте репозиторий голыми руками, ограничьтесь командами Git.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, точно... Я помню, что вы уже обьясняли и помню что удалял файл, но не нашел этот вопрос... Попробовал поискать файл но не нашел... но сейчас уже разобрался с первым вопросом... и со вторым тоже, только не до конца понял почему когда я склонировал репозиторий с `gitlab` себе на ноут и ввел команду `git branch -a` то показалась удаленая ветка `develop` хотя ее нет в удаленом репозитории... Значит она где то как ссылка храниться и при клонировании опять проявляется на локальной машине... Как тогда исправить это? Чтоб при клонировании она не появлялась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А когда я в терминале пишу команду git branch -a то получаю вот такой вывод

- master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master'

Ветки вида `remotes/origin/...` это так называемые tracking branches, "следящие ветки". Они "зеркалируют" ветки удалённого репозитория, настроенного у вас под именем `origin`. Когда вы выполняете `git fetch` или `git pull`, эти ветки обновляются. По ним вы можете узнать, какие ветки есть в репозитории origin и на какие коммиты они указывают. [(Подробнее.)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505118/181472)

> От куда подтягивается ветка remotes/origin/develop

Подтягивается из репозитория origin и указывает на тот же коммит, что и ветка develop в этом репозитории.

> remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master

Вы почти никогда не должны это удалять. [Указатель `remotes/origin/HEAD` отображает ветку, которая выбрана по умолчанию на удалённом репозиториии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543282/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-remotes-origin-head). Почти всегда это `master`. Это имеет значение при клонировании репозитория: ваша копия переключится именно на ту ветку и коммит, которые указаны в `remotes/origin/HEAD`.

**Только если репозиторий повреждён** и вы видите `warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/a`:

1. Сделайте бэкап репозитория - просто скопируйте папку `.git` куда-нибудь ещё.
2. [Пересоздайте указатель](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317072/git-repository-broken-after-computer-died):

   ```
   rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
   git fetch --all
   ```

> Как удалить ветку develop

Ответ тут: [Как удалить локальную ссылку на несуществующую уже удаленую ветку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577369/181472)